# How to get the sql state from libpq?

Tags: postgresql

I program with libpq.so. I want to get the error code which is called sql state in SQL Standard.How should I get this in my c code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The obvious Google search for `libpq get sqlstate`](http://google.com/search?q=libpq+get+sqlstate) finds [the libpq-exec documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html). Searching that for `SQLSTATE` finds `PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE` in the `PQresultErrorField` section.

Thus, you can see that you can call `PQresultErrorField(thePgResult, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE)` to get the `SQLSTATE`.

Answer (score 1):

*This is just addition I can not leave in form of comment due to reputation reasons.*

Note that you can not portably get SQLSTATE for errors that can occur during `PQconnectdb`. In theory, you can read `pg_conn` (internal struct) field `last_sqlstate` which contains correct value.

For example, if you try to connect with invalid login/password, it will give you `28P01`. For wrong database it will contain `3D000`.

I wish they defined publically available getter for this field.

You can check this one as well:
[libpq: How to get the error code after a failed PGconn connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349086/libpq-how-to-get-the-error-code-after-a-failed-pgconn-connection)

Comment: Please consider submitting a patch for this.