# How can an application determine a rollback?

Tags: c++, postgresql, transactions, rollback, libpqxx

I'm trying to determine if a transaction fails from the application.  How can this be done?

Further, is it possible to determine where a transaction failed, such as particular write that violates a constraint?

Comment: SQLstate, `PQresultStatus`, `PQerrorMessage`.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you Craig Ringer!  Would you mind upgrading to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular `libpq`, you would:

- Test the result of a query with `PQresultStatus`
- `PQresultErrorField(thePgResult, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE)` to get the `SQLSTATE`
- Use `PQerrorMessage` to get the error message for display to the user. *do not rely on parsing this in your application*, instead use the `SQLSTATE`, and the other fields in the result struct.

See [connection status functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-status.html), [libpq exec functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html) and the rest of the `libpq` documentation.

Related: [How to get the sql state from libpq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15779991/398670)

I have no experience with libpqxx, but I would expect it to wrap SQL errors into C++ exceptions with fields for the SQLState etc. See [the getting started guide for libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/4.0/html/Reference/a00001.html) and [the libpqxx exception classes reference](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/stable/html/Reference/a00200.html).

[This mailing list post](http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/libpqxx-general/2007-November/000040.html) and the replies in the thread will also be of interest, but be aware it's from 2007, and since then PostgreSQL has been extended to report more information in `PQresult`, like `PG_DIAG_CONSTRAINT_NAME`. No idea if libpqxx has been extended to take advantage of that, but you might be able to unwrap the exception to get an underlying `PQresult` if not.

There is, AFAIK, no way to get the actual value causing the issue except by showing the user the full error message. It'd be nice to change that.