# libpq: How to get the error code after a failed PGconn connection

Tags: postgresql, libpq

Given the following code.

```
PGconn* const conn=PQconnectdbParams(keywords, values, false);
if(! conn || PQstatus(conn)!=CONNECTION_OK){ /* error code? */ }
```

In case of a failed connection is there a way to get the error code to be able to 
distinguish between a bad password and the server being down.

(I know I can get the error message, but I want to be able to react to the cause of the 
error according to its cause).

Thanks.

Comment: From my deleted answer, note: `PQresultErrorField(conn, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE)` is *not* what's needed, because it acts on a `PGresult` from a query, not the `PGconn`. Interesting question. I see `PQconnectionNeedsPassword` and `PQconnectionUsedPassword` but they aren't really what you want.

Comment: Reading the sources, the `PGconn` struct has an internal `last_sqlstate` member but it doesn't appear to have an accessor. I suggest taking a look at the sources for `psql`, see if it differentiates the cases and if so how. Raise this as an issue on pgsql-general if you don't have any luck (and link back to this question).

Comment: From looking at the source code of psql, it seems they just print the error and exit. No help there.  if (PQstatus(pset.db) == CONNECTION_BAD)
 {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s", pset.progname, PQerrorMessage(pset.db));
  PQfinish(pset.db);
  exit(EXIT_BADCONN);
 }

Comment: From doing even more research it seems that the problems lies within libpq itself which simply doesn't report this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after doing some more research and asking postgres developers it seems that it is not currently possible to get the error code from PQconnectdbParams().

This seems to be a shortcoming of libpq itself which doesn't try to assign SQLState error codes for errors it detects internally (like an unknown hostname).

This seems to be on the postgres dev todo list but it's not a priority.

**TL;DR: If you are going to use libpq, learn to live with the text error message (whatever language it is localized in).**

Comment: It just occurred to me that you can attempt to send an empty query on the dead connection and probe the `PGresult` you get. But that won't work, the `PGresult` is just set to `NULL` if the connection is invalid. Pity.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
cout << PQerrorMessage(conn) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `getpeername()` on `PQsocket(conn)`.
In case of server being down `getpeername` return error, but in case of wrong password tcp connection was successfully established, and `getpeername` return server address.